# How to get rid of "/." in my result, when I evaluate a term containing ReplaceAll?

Tags: replacement, evaluation

In the previous code I defined `Bchoice` and `pchoice`

In one line I defined

```
Achoice := If[d > M^2/(3 V), ReplaceAll[(2 M - B d p)/(d (1 - p)), {B -> Bchoice, p -> pchoice}],0]
```

In the next line I want to calculate/simplify/evaluate `Achoice` under some assumptions, e.g.,

```
Assuming[V > 0 && d > M^2/(3 V), Simplify[Evaluate[Achoice]]]
```

But as an output I get

```
If[d > M^2/(3 V), (2 M - B d p)/(d (1 - p)) /. {B -> Bchoice, p -> pchoice}, 0]
```

But I want the expressions for `Bchoice` and `pchoice` already plugged into the result. for example `V` only appears inside `Bchoice`. How can I get the desired result? For example for certain assumptions if one plugs in all the expression, I expect that `Achoice` should be equal to zero, so I want Mathematica to output 0 in this case.

I am quite a beginner with Mathematica and I don't even really know what `Evaluate` actually means.

Comment: Try `Achoice := With[{B=Bchoice,p=pchoice},If[d>M^2/(3*V),(2*M-B*d*p)/(d*(1-p)),0]]` or `Achoice := With[{aux=(2*M-B*d*p)/(d*(1-p))/.{B->Bchoice,p->pchoice}},If[d>M^2/(3*V),aux,0]]`.

Comment: What version are you using? Your code evaluates fine on my machine, outputting: `(2 M - Bchoice d pchoice)/(d - d pchoice)`

Comment: @user293787 Super, this works very well. Now I use the `With` directly in the definition of `Achoice` instead of using `ReplaceAll`. Once I started using `ReplaceAll` I cannot fix it later in the code? But for now I am fine with rewriting the code removing all the `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Wolfram Mathematica 12.1

Comment: Weird, I'm on 12.0. Maybe I've got the buggy version :D

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `ReplaceAll` in general. You are using [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) here which does not evaluate its 2nd and 3rd argument as long as the 1st argument is not explicitly `True` or `False`. (There are good reasons for that. The 2nd and 3rd argument may contain long calculations, you do not want them to be carried out unless necessary. More severely, the 2nd and 3rd arguments could have side effects.) If a `ReplaceAll` is contained in `If`, then it is delayed. The `With` is one way to override this.

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion about naming things: If you use uppercase for variables or functions you may end up with conflicts against Mathematica global variables or functions (such as `N` or `E` or `I` etc.); good coding practice is to use lowercase.